# How to mole or moq e particular function which gets called in a static function

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, delegates, moles

I want to test a particular function. 
That function has call to static method of a different class which is protected thus cannot be access from outside.
 As I am doing component level testing I don't want to hit the database. 
So is it possible to mock a particular call to database if its inside a static function.

```
//I want to test this function
public void testing
{
    Abc.instance.Add();
}




class Abc
{
    public static readOnly instance = new Abc();

    Abc()
    {
        createInstance();
    }  

    public void createInstance()// I want to mock this function
    {
        //calls to the database
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But even if I use delegate to mock `createInstance()` , before even going to delegate line , static block is getting called, thus hitting the database and an exception is thrown.